# Email HTML table on iPhone stretches down the page

Tags: html, iphone

I have an HTML Table that is a email signature (code below). However on some iPhones (not all) the table stretches out down the page, i.e.
    C [new line]
    E [new line]
    N [new line]
    T [new line]
    R [new line]
    E [new line]
etc.
On android phones it is fine. Is there any way of stopping this behaviour?

```html
        <table cellspacing="2">
        <tr>
         <td rowspan="5" width="104">
         <a href="http://www.towers.com.au">
         <img alt="Centre Management Office" height="105" longdesc="Centre Management Office" src="CMO%20Logo.png" width="104" class="auto-style2"></a>
         </td>
         <td colspan="6" width="325">
         CENTRE MANAGEMENT OFFICE</td>
        <tr  style="font-size:7.5pt;">
         <td></td><td width="95">Unit 1203</td><td></td><td width="35">Phone:&nbsp;</td><td width="145">0</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr style="font-size:7.5pt;">
         <td></td><td>Tower 1</td><td></td><td>Fax:</td><td>0</td><td></td></tr>
        <tr style="font-size:7.5pt;">
         <td></td><td>&nbsp;Street</td><td></td><td>Email:</td>
         <td><a href="mailto:brian@email.com">brian@email.com</a></td><td></td></tr>
        <tr style="font-size:7.5pt;">
         <td></td><td class="auto-style3">Suburb</td><td></td><td>Web:</td>
         <td><a href="http://www.test.com.au">www.test.com.au</a></td><td></td></tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML "nowrap" attribute fixed the problem. Interestingly it causes the table to shrink (relative to other text on the page that is wrapped) in order to fit the table on the width of the phone screen.